# CodeIgniter Status Change

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Onclick the status will be changed to `Done` & again On click it will be changed to `Not Done`.

[image]

I'm unable to complete the `Controller` and `Model`.

View.php :

```
<td>
    <?php if ($row->task_status == 'todo') {echo "Not Done";} ?>
    <?php if ($row->task_status == 'done') {echo "Done";} ?>
</td>
```

DB :

```
`task_status` enum('notdone','done') NOT NULL
```

model.php :

```
public function change_status($id, $status)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('table_name')
     }
```

controller:

```
public function change_status()
        {
            $status = array( 'task_status' =>);

            $this->model_users->change_status_model($status, $this->input->post('id'));

            redirect('main/members');
        }
```

Comment: what is I'm unable to complete the Controller and Model. submit you code of controller. model and view what you have tried for it?

Comment: Where is the code accessing the controller action from script?

Comment: @saty I'm not sure what to put in controller, atm I'm just blank. But as you asked I edited and added some code.

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Edited, Please check the code :)

Comment: okk tell me how you call your controller code i mean by using ajax or you submit it using form method??

Comment: @saty That's what I want to know. How can I change the value when I click the status. for me form method would be easy. There must be something in controller which will get called and change the value, but my brain is not working at all :(

Comment: use jquery onclick function and by using ajax send your status to controller

Answer (score 0):

Set task_status column

```
public function change_status_model($task_status,$id)
{
    $this->db->set('task_status',$task_status)        
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table_name')
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by Set task_status column. & I think the $task_status is coming from Controller so please can you add the controller code kindly

Comment: You have pass status value from controller, but not use in model

Comment: Ok, I pass $task_status from controller to the method. But I need the code for $task_status by which I can change status.

Comment: using this $this->db->set('task_status',$task_status)  code, you can update status

Comment: My qsn was not about model, it was about the codes inside controller !

Comment: use jquery onclik function and pass id and status value