# CI pass array to model where clause

Tags: jquery, arrays, codeigniter

What I have so far after the discussions in the answers.

Declaration of array in JS:

```
var remove_rows = [];
var row_id = $(this).closest('div').find('row_id');
remove_rows.push(row_id);
```

Passing array to Controller using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: BASE_URL+'rows/deleterows',
  data: {batch:remove_rows},
  success: function(data){
         alert("Deleted!");
  }
});
```

Var_dump of `$data`

```
array(5) 
{ 
  [0]=> string(1) "1" 
  [1]=> string(1) "2" 
  [2]=> string(1) "3" 
  [3]=> string(1) "4" 
  [4]=> string(1) "5" 
}
```

Print_r of `$data`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 9
)
```

In my controller:

```
public function deleteRows(){
  $data = $this->input->post('batch');
  $this->Rows_model->deleteRows($data);
}
```

In my model:

```
public function deleteRows($data){
  $this->db->update_batch('rows', 'active', '0'); 
  $this->db->where('row_id', $data);
}
```

So basically I want to set all rows.active to 0 if the id is in the array.

I want to make it look like this:
`UPDATE table SET active = 0 WHERE row_id = 1 OR row_id = 2 OR row_id = 3...` in which the `row_id` IDs are from the array.

Comment: Than chk is it in proper array format as my other mate suggest the assume array

Comment: Use push as like that .... remove_rows.push(
   row_id);

Comment: What error r u getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
public function deleteRows($data){
    $this->db->set('active', '0'); // what is lacking 
    $this->db->where_in('row_id',$data);
    $this->db->update('rows'); 
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30045233/4620773).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
//assumeing $data=array(5,6,7);
$this->db->where_in('row_id', $data);
```

Comment: It's what I have and it doesn't seem to work. I don't know how to check what are the elements inside `$data`. If it only contains the numbers or what.

Comment: is_array is useful to check, if $data is in our proper array format or not apply it before where_in

Comment: one more idea, simple do var_dump($data) to know the proper format of $data either in controller or model

Comment: In this example no need to use update batch just simple update

Answer (score 1):

You can try like that with some checks:

**In controller check either data is array or not:**

```
public function deleteRows(){
  $data = $this->input->post('batch');

  if (is_array($data)){
     $this->Rows_model->deleteRows($data);
  }
}
```

**In model use where_in and remove batch update:**

```
public function deleteRows($data){


$this->db->where_in('row_id', $data);
$this->db->update('rows', 'active',0); 

}
```

In JS use push as like that:

```
    var remove_rows = []; 
var row_id = $(this).closest('div').find('row_id'); 
remove_rows.push(row_id);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. In the firebug. I have this in the POST parameters. `batch[] 7
batch[] 6 
batch[] 5 
batch[] 4 
batch[] 3`

Comment: One problem was this `url: BASE_URL+'/rows/deleterows',` but now I fixed it. Removed the `/` before rows. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I now got the var_dump. `array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" [4]=> string(1) "5" } `

Comment: Nope. When using `where_in` I get no error and doesn't work. But when I use `where` I get `Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 662`

Comment: Can u plz update the question with string... @iamdevlin

Comment: Are u using like that $this->db->where('row_string', 'stringvalue'); @iamdevlin

Comment: I'm using this `$this->db->where_in('row_id', $data);`

Comment: @iamdevlin if $data is an array than use where_in not where... where will only work for string or integer.

Comment: Yes. I am using where_in but still doesn't work. I didn't use `where` anymore.

Comment: Chk $data what r u geting? Print_r ($data);  @iamdevlin

Comment: It's already in my question. Everything in my question is what I have so far now.

Comment: I got the answer. I will put the answer that I found.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.